# URL value of property from config.properties file is put inside square brackets when composing the full request path if value has a portNumber at end

Tags: jmeter

I have a config.properties file where I put HOST and URI like this:

```
HOST=api-gate.abcd.test.asdf.ghjkl:2222
URI=//test/green/nct/some-verification
```

In JMeter, in the HTTP Request sampler I use the properties with `__P` to get the value of the property set in the .properties file like in this picture:
[image]

When I start the test and the request is composed and sent, Using the View Results Tree listener I can see the Sampler request body:

```
POST https://[api-gate.abcd.test.asdf.ghjkl:2222]//test/green/nct/some-verification
```

**The problem is that it ads the value of the HOST property inside these square brackets and it's actually not composing the request I want to send**. I want to compose my request like this:

```
POST https://api-gate.abcd.test.asdf.ghjkl:2222//test/green/nct/some-verification
```

I have tested and it's because of the :portNumber (:2222) being added to the HOST property value, but I don't understand why. If I remove the port number from the value of the HOST property in the config.properties file, the request gets composed as I expect it to, but when I add that port number, that's when the square brackets appear.

I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to share an update with the community that I found a solution to this, but I still don't understand why the tool works as it does.

The solution was to not specify the port as well in the string passed as a variable inside the "Server Name or IP" field, but use the "Port Number" field within the HTTP Request sampler and pass another defined variable in the config.properties file containing just the port number value into it.